# JSDoc object with value props as key

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, code-documentation

I have an `items` object with `Item`s like this:

```
class Item {
    /**
     *@type {number}
     */
    id;
}

let items = {};
```

I want to document the fact that keys of `items` is `value.id` is there a way ot do so?

Currently I'm using this syntax.

```
/**
 * @type {{[item_id:number]:Item}}
 */
let items = {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```js
/**
 * @type {Record<Item['id'], Item>}
 */
let items = {};
```

Comment: Nice one! Unfortunately I'm not using typescript, only js

Comment: @FiodarShurankou this example for JavaScript + JSDoc(with TypeScript). Here TypeScript used only for typechecking over jsdoc.